# ktor receive json body twice

Tags: exception, microservices, ktor

I cannot receive the json body of the ktor HttpClient twice.
For the server there is a DoubleReceive feature but I don't see how I can use this when doing client calls.

I want to call a different microservice which either returns some json or when there is an error it return e.g. status 500 and a error description a json payload.

so I tried to HttpResponseValidator and in this only allows a readBytes with this code

```
HttpResponseValidator {
validateResponse { response ->
  val statusCode = response.status.value
  val originCall = response.call

  if (statusCode < 300 || originCall.attributes.contains(ValidateMark)) return@validateResponse
  response.use {
    val exceptionCall = originCall.save().apply {
      attributes.put(ValidateMark, Unit)
    }
    //try parse error from json payload which other microservice usually send
    exceptionCall.response.receiveError()?.also { throw mapErrors(response, it) }
    //default ktor exception mapping
    when (statusCode) {
      in 300..399 -> throw RedirectResponseException(response)
      in 400..499 -> throw ClientRequestException(response)
      in 500..599 -> throw ServerResponseException(response)
    }
    if (statusCode >= 600) {
      throw ResponseException(response)
    }
  }
}
```

}

receiveError can be used as `JacksonConfig.defaultMapper.readValue<ServiceErrorResponse>(this.readBytes())` but will throw a DoubleReceivException if you just call `response.receive<ServiceErrorResponse>()`
The reason for this is that the receive function first checks a `received atomicBoolean`.

**TL;DR**
Now I wonder if there are any ideas on how you handle error payloads or do you just not use them? I am new to microservice in such a manner and it was a requirement to add them. Ktor is a new addition. How do you communicate error infromation between services?

Also is there a way to use the DoubleReceive feature in the client. Because `HttpClient(){install(DoubleReceive)}` does not work as it is not an ApplicationFeature and not a ClientFeature.

Comment: this is a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4225/

Answer (score 0):

Ktor has developed an experimental plugin called **Double Receive**, you can use it to receive request body as much as you want.

Read more: https://ktor.io/docs/double-receive.html

Comment: This is not for client, only for Server request handlers

Comment: Did you find one for client?